# Finding the process that is using a certain port in Linux

Tags: linux, port

I'd like to be able to find out which process is currently using a certain port in Linux. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: On Windows, the command is :  `netstat -anb`

Answer (score 167, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

```
lsof -i tcp:80
```

will give you the list of processes using tcp port 80.

Alternatively,

```
sudo netstat -nlp
```

will give you all open network connections.

Comment: `lsof -i | grep {username}` is also very useful, i.e. `lsof -i | grep apache`

Comment: For anyone wondering, `-n` : don't resolve names, `-l` : display listening server sockets, `-p` : display PID/Program name for sockets.

Comment: I usually add `-P` to `lsof -i tcp:$PORTNUMBER` so that the port gets printed back to me as a number.

Comment: You also need an sudo on the lsof line, else it will *silently* fail.

Answer (score 11):

I am using "CentOS 7 minimal" which has nor `netstat` neither `lsof`. But a lot of linux distributions have the socket statistics command (i.e. `ss`).

Here is an example of execution:

```
# ss -tanp | grep 6379
LISTEN   0    128  127.0.0.1:6379   *:*   users:(("redis-server",pid=2531,fd=4))
```

Answer (score 10):

```
netstat -lp
```

Comment: on mac you have to add a protocol option to -p. so something like: netstat -lp tcp.

Answer (score 3):

In Linux, To find a process running on a port, do below:

```
lsof -i :<port_number>
```

example:

```
lsof -i :8080
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. This command was mentioned in the accepted answer. If you have something new, please edit your post.

Answer (score 0):

also if you want to list running processes that are speaking TCP you can use

```
sudo netstat -tnp

    sudo to get processes you don't own
    -t for TCP
    -n for numeric
    -p for pid
```

to get processes speaking UDP replace the -t with a -u

```
sudo netstat -unp
```