# How do I determine which application is using port 8080?

Tags: linux, port, http

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding the process that is using a certain port in linux](https://superuser.com/questions/42843/finding-the-process-that-is-using-a-certain-port-in-linux)

I have an Ubuntu Server setup, where I'm trying to set up a daemon that wants to have access to port 8080. When I run the command, the error message says it's being used by another process. But which one, it doesn't say. How can I go about finding which program uses this port?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can see the command that occupies port 8080 by issuing e.g. `lsof -i :8080` or `netstat -tulpn | grep :8080`.