# Finding all processes that are using a given port

Tags: linux, process, tcp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding the process that is using a certain port in Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/42843/finding-the-process-that-is-using-a-certain-port-in-linux)

More specifically, how can I find out what processes are using port 8080 (for example a web server)?

Answer (score 4):

Using:

```
lsof -i :8080
```

Comment: that one seems to also return client conenctions

Comment: @thejh: OK, so grep for `LISTEN` to only get the server connections

Answer (score 2):

```
netstat -n --tcp -p -l |grep ":8080"
```

Comment: `netstat -ntpl`

Comment: Note: You have to be root to return general process/port relationships.  You will get your own if you have created them, but others will not show up if you don't own those processes.