# How can I find out which process is listening on a port on linux?

Tags: linux, http, process, port

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding the process that is using a certain port in Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/42843/finding-the-process-that-is-using-a-certain-port-in-linux)

How can I find out which process is listening on a port on linux?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

as root

```
sudo lsof -i
sudo netstat -lptu
```

Comment: I generally do: "sudo netstat -anp | grep port_number"

Comment: i like `netstat -tnlp`

Answer (score 6):

With `lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN` you get a list of all TCP ports in state LISTEN and their associated processes (command and pid are in the first two columns).

Answer (score 3):

you can use "netstat"

```
netstat -anp | less
```

will show you the PID and process name as the last column, checkout "man netstat" if you want to change the options

Answer (score 0):

You can use [netstat](http://linux.die.net/man/8/netstat) to list all processes listening on some port. But I don't how to filter for a specific one.

Answer (score 0):

`netstat` should help if you are on Linux. For more information see [`man netstat`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/netstat).