# How do I find (and kill) process running on a certain port?

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding the process that is using a certain port in Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/42843/finding-the-process-that-is-using-a-certain-port-in-linux)

I'm using Ubuntu Linux 11.04.  How do I write a shell script expression that will find the process running on port 4444 and then kill the process?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate as it is asking how to kill, not find, the process on the port: fuser -k 9000/tcp

Answer (score 49):

You could use `lsof` to find the process:

```
lsof -t -i:4444
```

would list only the pid of the process listening on port 4444. You could just say

```
kill `lsof -t -i:4444`
```

if you were brave.

Comment: +1 for 'if you were brave.'

Answer (score 7):

You use `lsof`:

```
# lsof -n | grep TCP | grep LISTEN | grep 4444
```

The output will be something like:

```
pname 16125 user 28u IPv6 4835296 TCP *:4444 (LISTEN)
```

Where the first column is the process name, and the second column is the process id. You then parse the output, find out what the process id (PID) is and use `kill` command to kill it.

Comment: I'd never heard of lsof before.  Looking at the man page, it appears to be incredibly useful.  Thanks!

Comment: everything in linux is a file and lsof lets you find files so... yeah, very useful

Answer (score 3):

```
kill -9 `netstat -lanp --protocol=inet | grep 4444 | awk -F" " '{print $7}' | awk -F"/" '{print $1}'`
```

Uses netstat to list listening INET sockets with numeric ports and parent processes. Filters for string 4444, takes out the 7th column( pid/process name ) and further splits it by "/" to get the pid. Passes that to kill command.

Comment: I'd recommend against the kill -9. It doesn't allow cleanup, and some internet app is more likely to have resources that need to be shut down cleanly.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you could use `netstat -ap` if `lsof` is not available on you system (as it isn't on a busybox system I work with regularly).

Comment: good call, I was wondering why this wasn't working on a busybox derived docker image I was working on