# Linux Remove Previous nc Directive

Tags: netcat

I need to use `nc -lp4 5432 --allow 192.168.1.24` but I have a previous `nc` directive that only has it listening on `localhost`.  It throws an error when I try overwriting it:

```
$ nc -lp4 5432 --allow 192.168.1.24
Ncat: Got more than one port specification: 4 5432. QUITTING.
```

How can I overwrite the previous instruction, or delete that listener?  I've had a look around and I can't find how to get this removed.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> $ nc -lp4 5432 --allow 192.168.1.24
> Ncat: Got more than one port specification: 4 5432. QUITTING.
> ```

This has nothing to do with "previous" whatever. The error states that `4` (the option-argument for `-p`) and `5432` both specify the port, but `nc` that is about to listen (i.e. with `-l`) expects at most one port specified in the command line.

If you want to use `5432` and not `4` then either use `-p 5432` or don't use `-p` at all. Any of these will work (one at a time), they are equivalent:

```
nc -l -p 5432 --allow 192.168.1.24
nc -l -p5432 --allow 192.168.1.24
nc -lp 5432 --allow 192.168.1.24
nc -lp5432 --allow 192.168.1.24
nc -l 5432 --allow 192.168.1.24
```

Comment: `[Mon Jul 11 02:17:11 root@server_n ~] nc -l -p 5432 --allow 192.168.1.24
Ncat: bind to :::5432: Address already in use. QUITTING.`  The `port` seems already bound.

Comment: @Rich_F [How do I find (and kill) process running on a certain port?](https://superuser.com/q/322363/432690)

Comment: Interesting there is no command to overwrite or delete it.  Thank you.

Comment: @Rich_F A new `nc` is a standalone process, not a command line interface for some "nc service" that could be reconfigured.

Comment: Mine is up and down.  I get connected, then disconnected on another try.  That did kill the process though.  Is there a way to make this permanent?

Comment: @Rich_F Let's not go [chameleon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/355310). Ask a new question if you need. I'm not sure what you're describing, maybe this will be a helpful start: your listening `nc` accepts and processes exactly one connection, then it exits, it's by design.

Comment: OK, that's fine.  I thought this was a permanent `listener`.

Comment: @Rich_F Oh, this. There is `nc -k`. See `man 1 nc`.

Comment: @Rich_F If you need something more complex, then use `socat`. See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/549505/108618) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/578881/108618).

Comment: Just trying to get a `postgresql` port alive and listening 24/7.  I don't think `nc` is an option.  I'm sure there's a true way to get this to work.  I will keep `socat` in mind.