# Find out which port the daemon is using

Tags: linux, unix, port, daemon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding the process that is using a certain port in Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/42843/finding-the-process-that-is-using-a-certain-port-in-linux)

Suppose I run some daemon but I didn't remember which port it usually use.
How can I obtain this information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`netstat`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/netstat) tool. For example:

`netstat -pan`

Look under the section that says "LISTEN" and it will tell you what ports the daemons are listening on. Note that you should run this as root unless the daemon is running as the user you're logged in as.