# Map open port to process

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding the process that is using a certain port in Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/42843/finding-the-process-that-is-using-a-certain-port-in-linux)

How may I find out which process(daemon) is listening on a given port if I do not have a service that would specifically listen on that port?
   For example if port 10101 is open how can I close the respective process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use lsof (list open files) to get the Process ID.

E.g. `lsof | grep 10101`

Then use can get the process name from /proc (`cd /proc/processIDnumber`).

Comment: Yes. A more specific way would be lsof -i :10101

Comment: Thank. I was struggling with the man page which is somehow messed up on my system.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `netstat -tulpn` and grep for the name of the port.

For instance, using your example port, the command would be `netstat -tulpn | grep 10101`